# How do I install windows 7 as a dual boot alongside windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, windows-installation

I have windows 10 installed on a UEFI system. I'm looking to install Windows 7 Pro 64 bit to have the option when I boot between Windows 7 and Windows 10. The problem I think is that it's a UEFI system. I've tried going into the BIOS and putting in into legacy support mode. I've got a USB with Win 7 on it, and a partition (on the hard drive windows 10 is installed onto) created for the install. When I boot into Win 7 setup it gets as far as selecting the drive to install to, but it won't let me install onto the set aside partition. It says "windows 7 cannot be installed the selected disk is of the GPT partition style". I tried googling the problem, but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, and don't understand the possible solutions. Does anyone know how to help me? And if you do, can you put it in such a way that an idiot like me can understand?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to boot with the firmware in EFI mode and from a EFI compatible windows installation (e.g. a windows 7 x64 DVDROM or a pendrive with the correct files) and use a disk partitoned in GPT style,

**or**

You can boot from a BIOS or with the EFI firmware in legacy mode. In this case it will install on a disk which must be partitioned in the classic MBR style.

You cannot combine legacy mode and GPT.

The message `windows 7 cannot be installed the selected disk is of the GPT partition style.` seems to indicate that you are booting in legacy mode.

Comment: OK, so if I just turn off legacy support mode in the bios and boot as normal, selecting the USB as the boot device, I should be able to install 7 no problem?  The install files are Win 7 Pro 64 bit, on a USB stick.

Comment: Yes, though youi might need to point not at just the USB pendrive, but at the actual .efi file on that drive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really only need windows 7 some times.

What about running windows 7 as a virtual install from within Windows 10, using the "Hyper-V" (which is free and built into windows 10).

Comment: Nothing wrong in the answer but it is not what OP is asking for. It must be a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

only answer I've seen that seems reliable is to by a 2nd hard drive, and 
install each to separate drives. a pain, yes, but the only option since
windows won't install anywhere but the boot partition.